# const correctness with this

Tags: c++, constants, const-correctness

I have a const method in which I want to set an attribute of a member of class B to the current instance A (to make a backreference by pointer)

Class A:

```
void A::foo () const
{
   ...
   ...
   B b;
   b.setA(this);
   ...
}
```

Class B:

```
setA(A * Ap){
   this->pointerToA = Ap;
}

B * getA() {return pointerToA;}

A* pointerToA;
```

The compiler doesnt allow this... Ok
Now I tried to

Class B:

```
setA(const A * Ap){
   this->pointerToA = Ap;
}

const A * getA() {return pointerToA;}

const A* pointerToA;
```

This solves the original problem, but now I cannot call in B:

```
...
this->getA()->anotherMethodOfA();
...
```

because I get "cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const A' to 'A&'

Although I understand the upper problem, I cannot figure out, how to call the other method now and what's the problem...Why is there a A& in the error message, since I have nowhere a reference to A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since A is a constant pointer, you can only call `const` methods on it. There are two possible solutions:

1. if you need to call a non-const method on A: remove the `const` specifier from `void A::foo () const`, since the function is actually modifying `this` through the calls to B.
2. if you don't need to call a non-const method on A: make `anotherMethodOfA` and any other method invoked on A inside B `const` too.

The error you get is legitimate, otherwise you would be violating the definition of pure method.

If you need `foo` to be `const` and the methods invoked on A inside `foo` do not change it in a way that is visible through the public interface (e.g. perform some caching or the like), you could also try using the `mutable` specifier with modified fields. But don't abuse this feature, please!

Comment: ;-) 2. helped. Of course anotherMethodOfA  must be const, otherwise the object can be modified. Thnks for the tip - I struggled for hours on that and now it became 100% clear...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by using `Scott Meyers'` solution: Two versions of all getters, one `non-const` version that calls the `const` version and the `const` version returns the intended variable:

```
const A* GetA() const { return pointerToA; }
//Cast 'this' to a const reference to B
//(this allows you to call the const version of the getter instead of infinite recursion).
//Cast away the const-ness of the result returned by the const version
//and return the non-const version.
A* GetA() { return const_cast<A*>(static_cast<const B&>(*this).getA()); }
```